# MySQL, DELETE Query with a Join

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone help me understand what's wrong with this query:

```
DELETE FROM noteproject 
INNER JOIN note ON noteproject.noteID = note.noteID
INNER JOIN person ON note.personID = person.personID
WHERE noteID = '#attributes.noteID#' 
  AND personID = '#attributes.personID#'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why what you are trying to use doesn't work, is because [MySQL doesn't support join syntax in the delete statement in the manner you tried](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Use:

```
DELETE FROM NOTEPROJECT
 WHERE noteID = '#attributes.noteID#' 
   AND note_id IN (SELECT n.note_id 
                     FROM NOTE n
                    WHERE n.personID = '#attributes.personID#')
```

...or using EXISTS:

```
DELETE FROM NOTEPROJECT
 WHERE noteID = '#attributes.noteID#' 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM NOTE n
                WHERE n.note_id = note_id
                  AND n.personID = '#attributes.personID#')
```

Comment: While this may work, @AlbertoZaccagni's answer below may be better suited for certain situations (including large amounts of data).

Answer (score 9):

I have no db at the moment to test what I'm saying, but [here's a reference to the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) where your case is taken as an example:

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the particular condition in the WHERE clause.

And also:

> 1) For the first multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed before the FROM clause are deleted.
>   2)For the second multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed in the FROM clause (before the USING clause) are deleted.
>  The effect is that you can delete rows from many tables at the same time and have additional tables that are used only for searching:

```
1)
DELETE t1, t2 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;

2)
DELETE FROM t1, t2 
USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> These statements use all three tables when searching for rows to delete, but delete matching rows only from tables t1 and t2.

Answer (score 3):

Tested with MySQL 5.1.41:

```
DELETE np
FROM noteproject np
INNER JOIN note n ON np.noteID = n.noteID
INNER JOIN person p ON n.personID = p.personID
WHERE n.noteID = '#attributes.noteID#' 
  AND p.personID = '#attributes.personID#';
```

Explanation:

- You need to qualify `noteID` and `personID` with table names or table aliases in the `WHERE` clause, or else MySQL complains that they're ambiguous (because the column exists in more than one table).
- Check the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html) for multi-table `DELETE`.  There are a couple of different forms but you weren't matching any of the legal syntax forms.

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
DELETE noteproject FROM noteproject 
INNER JOIN ...
```

Alternatively, you can write:

```
DELETE FROM noteproject USING noteproject
INNER JOIN ...
```

Comment: `DELETE noteproject FROM noteproject` is incorrect syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: That page gives the example: DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;

Answer (score 0):

Try in the WHERE part

```
tblname.noteID = '#attributes.noteID#' AND tblname.personID = '#attributes.personID#'
```