# How to DELETE, UPDATE from SQL table with double INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, inner-join, sql-delete

Well, I'm doing a database for a restaurant so, it has a table of clients(`clientes`), a menu(`receitas`), and a list of orders(`pedidos`). I need to have the client and the food the client is asking in the order, and in case I need to change the menu database, or a data from the client, like the name I wouldn't like to have the trouble to change all the current data from the table `pedidos`, that's why I used the JOIN.

I have 3 SQL tables: Pedidos, Clientes, Receitas.

I used 2 Inner Joins to relate these tables, because I want the order(Pedido) to content the id of the client(cliente) who bought it and the id from the relative recipe(receitas).

Here's a link to download the sql file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11R5w5XuPd5G1MkjJ17szlWmnvX_x2YZH

For SELECT a specific data from the table `pedidos` filtering the value of the `idpedido`, I use this query and it works just fine, It returns me the specific row from the table `pedidos` that has the `idpedido` = 7:

```
"SELECT pedidos.idpedido, clientes.nome as cnome, clientes.endereco, clientes.cpf, clientes.tel ,receitas.nome ,pedidos.preco, pedidos.data, pedidos.hora, pedidos.status 
FROM pedidos 
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.idcliente = pedidos.cliente 
INNER JOIN receitas ON receitas.idreceita = pedidos.receita 
WHERE pedidos.idpedido = 7"
```

I'm trying to delete a specific row from the table `pedidos` which has the value of the the column `idpedido` = 7 with this code:

```
$query="DELETE FROM pedidos
INNER JOIN clientes ON clientes.idcliente = pedidos.cliente
INNER JOIN receitas ON receitas.idreceita = pedidos.receita
WHERE pedidos.idpedido = 7";
$resultDelete=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$row=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
echo $row;
```

and it echos 0, I guess that means the code is not giving me an error, just that the affected_rows = 0, coz It cannot find the right row.

but What is bugging me is that I'm filtering properly with the SELECT (It's returning the row which has the `idpedido` value = 7), but with the DELETE it just doesn't filter the right row, coz the affected rows are = 0.

I'd like to know which is the right $QUERY that would filter the specific row from the table `pedidos` that has the `idpedido` = 7 and delete it, that is my goal with this question.

Comment: From which table(s) are you trying to delete?  Where are you doing an update?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you tell me that everytime :) but I'm trying to get the OP to correct it rather than always do it for them.

Comment: Feel free to set up a db-fiddle (instead of pasting a screenshot of your table), so that volunteers to can test their suggestions.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. Put everything needed in your post not just at a link. [ask] [help]

Comment: Please, please, please, with a Strawberry on top, take this advice: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2943403

Comment: What is the point of joining the extra tables if they are irrelevant to the filtering of the data?  Why are is `pedidos`,`clientes`,`receitas` written between `DELETE` and `FROM`?  Do you _actually_ wish to set those column values to `NULL` or do you _actually_ want to kill the whole row?

Comment: Please address everything in my comment. PS For errors a [mre] includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) PS It is good to get a query/select correct before continuing with a related delete.

Comment: Yes, I actually just bothered to open up your google drive link.  That goes in the db-fiddle, then your query on the right side, then we need to understand your desired outcome.

Comment: "Justify what you think your code does by reference to the manual for the syntax/functionality you are using" (etc etc etc) Should I use bold italics uppercase?

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Googling 'site: stackoverlfow.com mysql delete using joins before:2011' ...

Comment: Duplicate of [MySQL, DELETE Query with a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1962185/3404097)

Comment: PS site:stackoverflow.com php mysqli get mysql error messages before:2011

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete from first table only, then write your query like this:

```
DELETE a FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id AND b.id AND a.id = 123
```

Comment: My advice is that why mentioned three table to delete before FROM  keyword. Only keep one table 'pedidos'

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. This answer & your comment are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please don't answer unclear or duplicate questions. They should be closed. This question doesn't clearly say what is wanted. A thing that is wrong no matter what about some wrong code in it is an easily found duplicate question.